# Windows 10 + Roaming Aggressiveness to highest but not wireless network switch?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-roaming

Windows 10, Realtek latest driver, Roaming Aggressiveness to highest, I can see in wifi network status that the signal goes down and down, and I've another wireless network with stronger signal, and it doesn't change to the strongest wifi network.

I think roaming agressiveness should force to this switch, shouldn't?

Answer (score 2):

The setting has nothing to do with switching between networks. "Roaming" means jumping between access points belonging to the *same* network (that is, having the same SSID aka "network name"). For example, Wi-Fi at a university or company would be provided by dozens of APs all having identical names (SSIDs), so you'd only see one network in the list, but your device would automatically switch APs as you move – similar to a cell phone switching towers.

The difference is: When you roam *within* a network, there is a minor interruption but your IP address remains the same and your connections remain active. When you switch networks *completely* then all connections will break. (For example, VoIP calls, or multiplayer games, would completely disconnect.) So usually the system will *not* automatically switch networks for as long as the old one is still somewhat usable, and this setting does not change that.

Comment: By wireless networks, he doesn't mean two separate subnets.  He means 2 wireless APs on the same network/subnet with a windows 10 machines roaming between the APs.

Comment: @pythonian: The OP said "another wireless network", which implies a different SSID. The OS doesn't know up-front whether it'll belong to the same IP subnet – as long as SSIDs are different, it assumes that the IP networks will also be different, and will avoid jumping.

Comment: I guess we will need the author to clarify.